# Definition of dllimport static field not allowed with Qt Creator and Cocos2d

Tags: c++, qt-creator, cocos2d-x

I have been given a task to make a qt project originally created on Mac run on Windows. It needs to use MinGW (g++ and gcc) for compilation.

I had problems with `_WIN32` and `_WINDOWS` not being defined when trying to build the project (although it says in settings that they were), so I just hardcoded that bit for the time being.
I also had to add `GL\glew.h` and `ft2build.h` and whole freetype library to have all the required files for win32 version of cocos2d.

However, Qt Creator is now complaining that I'm defining `dllimport` static fields for most of Cocos2d objects. There are also thousands of warnings that bunch of objects are being redeclared without `dllimport` attribute. I haven't touched Cocos2d files (other than the platform one where I forced it to use win32).

What am I doing wrong (other than the hardcoding bit)?

Comment: `dllimport` and its counterpart `dllexport` are usually conditionally defined using macros.  You probably have the conditional `#define` unset that chooses which one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to define `_WIN32` and `_WINDOWS` in the project menu of the QtCreator as additional arguments for make to avoid the hardcoding. I also had to define `CC_STATIC` to prevent Cocos2d to insert the `dllimport` or `dllexport` before each of the functions. The arguments I added were:

```
DEFINES+="_WIN32 _WINDOWS CC_STATIC"
```